# Вывод номера строки отсортированной таблицы

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Итак, я вновь продолжаю изучение SQL. Спасибо за вашу поддержку.
На сей раз у меня новые трудности:
Предположим, у меня есть вот такой запрос

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`nick`, COUNT(`user_id`) AS total
FROM (`actions`)
RIGHT JOIN `users` ON `actions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `total` desc
LIMIT 10
```

который выдает вот такое результат (скриншот из phpMyAdmin).
Вопрос такой: как вывести на какой позиции в уже отсортированной таблице находится пользователь, с id равным например 19 (igola)

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Количество пропущенных записей + номер в полученной выдаче. Я не шучу, это действительно делается таким образом внутри произвольного ЯП, потому что номер строки - довольно неприменимое к SQL понятие. Это можно сделать за счет переменной, но я повторюсь - это должно делаться внутри ЯП, и при этом надо понимать, что формально такой номер мало на что будет указывать - банально к моменту попадания этих данных к пользователю этот номер может изменить свое значение.

Comment: @Etki ЯП? Что это? Что гуглить?

Comment: @igolka97 язык программирования

Comment: @Etki А что делать, если на деле мне надо будет убрать `LIMIT 10` и находить пользователя который находится на 9999999 месте?( сервер не упадет ли?

Comment: @Etki читал о том, что можно пронумеровать эти строки в таблице, но получалось у меня только их пронумеровать только в неотсортированной таблице. А потом просто изъять номер строки

Comment: @igolka97,

> А что делать, если на деле мне надо будет убрать LIMIT 10 и находить пользователя который находится на 9999999 месте?

Не понял вопроса (как это связано с нумерацией?), но LIMIT 9999990, 10

> читал о том, что можно пронумеровать эти строки в таблице, но получалось у меня только их пронумеровать только в неотсортированной таблице.

потому что (еще раз) их и не надо там нумеровать.

Comment: @Etki ну если убрать  limit 10 то мы увидим 1000000 записей, и пока  foreach  будет проходить по всем полученным 1000000 строкам сервер может упать даже) поэтому я ищу методы оптимизации за счет  sql

Comment: @igolka97, я и написал - select * from X limit 999990, 10. Пропустит 999990 записей, выведет десять. Вот с тем, что ему придется как минимум один раз пройти по всем записям, ничего не сделать, к сожалению, но это отразится только во времени выполнения запроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> select @a:=0;
mysql> select @a:=@a+1, aa.* from (SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`nick`, 
COUNT(`user_id`) AS total
FROM (`actions`)
RIGHT JOIN `users` ON `actions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `total` desc
LIMIT 10) aa;
```

В результате получите нужную вам выборку, но будет-ли это работать где-нибудь, кроме как в mysql-консоли, я не проверял, но подозреваю, что нет.

Предполагая, что сами по себе sql-запросы существуют только в учебниках, а на практике - они часть приложений, написанных на каком-либо языке программирования, могу предложить следующее:

```
var res_ar = [];
var sql = "ваш_сложный_и_мощный_запрос";
var res_query = sql_query(sql);
res_ar = sql_fetch_to_array(res_query);
  print "ROW N \t\t ID \t\t USER \t\t TOTAL\n";
for (var i=0; i<count(res_ar); i++) {
  print i,"\t\t",res_ar[i][id],"\t\t",res_ar[i][user],"\t\t",res_ar[i][total],"\n"
}
```

Так вы выведите на экран (веб-страницу/файл/плоттер) вашу выборку пронумерованной.

Answer (score 0):

Нумеровать строки при отсутствии ранжирующих ФУНКЦИЙ как-то лениво. Почитайте [здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_numbering_rows_in_query.html).

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь [@boris_U](/users/30380/boris_u), без которого бы я так и не пришел сам к верному ответу. Мда, запрос, конечно, получился такой ни/;*^$\ый, но получился!) и время обработки заняло всего лишь 0.00045 секунды. Ну, а теперь сам запрос:

```
SELECT ab.* from (select @a:=@a+1 as num, aa.* from
(SELECT `users`.`id`, `users`.`nick`, COUNT(`user_id`) AS total
FROM (`actions`)
RIGHT JOIN `users` ON `actions`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `total` desc) 
aa, (select @a:=0) as z) ab where id = 19
```

Три вложенных запроса решили мою проблему  :D всем спасибо:)